# Error when calling CPLEX in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cplex

I am using cplex12.5 (x86-32) academic version with win7 (32bit) and Matlab 2009a (32bit).
I tried a simple linear problem using cplexlp function in Matlab. The following error has appeared:

```
Error using ==> cplexlp at 254
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Program
Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Preview125\cplex\matlab\x86_win32\cplexlink125.mexw32': The specified module could not be found.
```

What's the problem? Is there any way to solve it?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: did you compile the C/C++ file as mex?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means a dependent library is missing or not in the path. You can find what is missing by opening your mex file in dependency walker. Google for depends.exe to download dependency walker.